# Roku Transfer Roku Channel

Tags: roku, brightscript

we have roku app or channel in different developer account and we want to transfer that channel to another account so ,is it possible to transfer a Roku App (Channel) from a roku developer account to another developer account? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no readily available method for transferring a channel. As far as I'm aware, the only possibility would be asking Roku partner success / developer support if they might be able to help move an existing channel to a different developer account https://developer.roku.com/contact